# background-attachement property and layout

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to position background images. The problem I have is that the background image makes the copy difficult to read on some screen sizes. This is because the image is a tree branch which, depending on screen size, sometimes underlaps the text on the page.

To get around this I set a min-height on the body - fine.

I wouldlike to keep the effect of the a fixed value of the background-attachement property though:

```
html {background-attachement: fixed;}
```

I like how the elements on top of the html scroll while the html background images remain static.

However, when I set the following code the min-height of the body loses it's effect - the image gets in the way of the copy:

```
html {background-attachement:fixed;}
body {min-height:900px;)
```

You can see the issue if you set "html {background-attachement: fixed} here: http://tinyurl.com/7sctwak

Any advice on how to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried background-attachement: scroll;

Comment: @Connor yes but that doesn't achieve the effect I want. I want the fixed effect while maintaining enough space between the two background images (height) so that there is no background to the text/copy. Thanks all the same though

Comment: You don't have any background-attachment set in your css from that link (scroll is the default, so that's what it currently is).

Comment: there is now if you manage to re-check - it's set on the html. If your on a laptop like me you'll see the issue right away - the copy is difficult to read and I'd like to create some space/gap between the two background images to get around this.

Comment: the main copy on the home page - you'll only see this if your on a smaller screen, I'm on a laptop about 10" in height

Comment: What's you're screen resolution?

Comment: just checked its actually 1280 * 800

Comment: Why don't you just make the text area's background a higher opacity. Something like background-color: rgba(250, 255, 255, 0.6);

Comment: Yep, good solution and I've implemented it. What I'm holding out for though is a way to set background attachment as fixed in conjunction with a min-height property, as the former seems to override the latter. Thanks for your help and input